# Java process inside Docker ended without any error or OOM Kill

Tags: java, docker

I am running docker container (Version 18.09.1) and a Java process (JDK 1.8.0_212) inside the docker container. The docker container has been started with no memory limits and i can see using docker stats that the limit is the entire 31 GB of RAM available on the parent VM (Debian GNU Linux 10).
The Java application is started with 18 GB of heap and the RES memory stays somewhere around the 20.5 GB mark as shown in the top command.

Every now and then in a few days (5-7) , the java process inside the docker container will end without any errors. The logs just stop for a while and there are no OutOfMemory or any other errors whatsoever.
I checked the dmesg/syslog/kernel logs for any OOM Kill messages but there are none whatsoever , not even for any other processes.

I have checked the cgroup limits for my container (/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/containerID) and the memory.limit_in_bytes seems to be an enormous value of (9223372036854771712) which has confused me further.

Any help in understanding what could cause the process to just stop would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where will the JVM write it’s own crash logs and core dumps?

Comment: I guess that will be in the Java folder itself.

Comment: Then look there - you might be lucky

Comment: Thanks for the replies , this issue disappeared on its own and start recurring now again.
Usually we will get a OutofMemoryError in logs and the JVM process is still running for us to take a heap dump.
But when this happens we don't get any error in the logs and the logs stop abruptly and there is no crash or dump in java folder , neither can i find anything in the syslogs/dmesg for OOM Killer invocation. It hits a dead end with no alternative but to restart the process.